# How to write a rule to notify about metric updates?

Tags: metrics, notify, prometheus

I'v configured exporter for PostgreSQL logs. Exporter is looking for new log messages with level Error or Fatal. Prometheus is checking this exporter and scraping metrics in format:
psql_errors{instance='',level='',message=''}

Now i want to make alert rule to notify me about any new error. Using of operators like increase() or changes() did not help. So i am asking someone for help

For example, current rule is next:

```
ALERT psql_error
  IF changes({job='psql-grokexporter',level='ERROR'}[1m]) > 0
  ANNOTATIONS {
    summary = "PostgreSQL Error in logs",
    description = "PSQL error: {{ $labels.message }} at {{ $labels.instance }}",
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an event logging use case for which Prometheus isn't really suited., as you're exporting per-message I'd suggest using a system such as ELK for this instead.